# Chrome extension variable doesn't change on tab loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, content-script

I want to make a Chrome extension which check the network resources and, selecting an image by its url, download it to client computer.
I'm new to chrome extension (even though I understand javascript), so I checked on Google and I got to this thread: [How to log fetched network resources in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430787/how-to-log-fetched-network-resources-in-javascript)
background.js:

```
    var aNetworkLog = [];

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(oCompleted) {
        var sCompleted = JSON.stringify(oCompleted);
        aNetworkLog.push(sCompleted);
    }
    ,{urls: ["http://*/*"]}
 );

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.action == "getNetworkLog") {
        port.postMessage(aNetworkLog);
    }
});
});
```

content_script.js:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name:'test'});

document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", function() {

port.postMessage({action:"getNetworkLog"});

}, false);

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
string = "";
for (i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
   var res = msg[i]; 
    var x = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
    if (x.type == "image"){
        var vars = parse_url(x.url);
        if (typeof vars['query'] !== 'undefined' && typeof vars['host'] !== 'undefined'){
        if (vars['host'] == 'myhostname' &&   vars['query'].indexOf('whatiwantinurl') != -1 && vars['query'].indexOf('whatidontwantinurl') == -1){
           url = x.url;
           break;
        }
        }


    }
}

SaveToDisk(url,'download.png');
$('#next').click();

});

function SaveToDisk(fileURL, fileName) {
// for non-IE
if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = fileURL;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}
```

Parse_url function: http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/.
The script check every resource until it finds the one I want and then download it.
It works correctly just the first time after I install the extension: if I change the tab, and there is an other resource that match the url requirements, then the script download the first resource, of the firs tab (when I click the menu obj in the second tab), instead of downloading the new image. That means that the url variable doesn't change (and I checked it!) 
I'm asking why.
Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Have you tried debugging? is `url` changing? do you get to the point where you do `url = x.url;` at the appropiate conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood it completely but the problem is probably that the aNetworkLog is a global variable that resides in your background page context which lives as long as browser is working. That's why every time you do the loop `for (i=0;i<msg.length;i++)` you start checking the same requests over and over. It's no wonder then that it always finds the first matching request.

I guess what you need is probably check only requests related to the current tab.

background.js

```
var aNetworkLog = null;
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    aNetworkLog = new Array(); // reset the array every time the active tab is changed
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(oCompleted) {
        aNetworkLog.push(sCompleted);
    }
    ,{tabId: activeInfo.tabId, urls: ["http://*/*"]}
    );
});
```

Here tabs.onActivated could be also tabs.onUpdated and tabs.onCreated depending on your goal (which I don't really get) and then you'd have to maintain an array of urls for every tabId, not only for the active one. In the latter case you would distinguish the required tabId through port's tabId property, i.e.

```
var aListOfNetworkLogs = new Object();
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {  // or onCreated()
     aListOfNetworkLogs[tab.id] = new Array();
     ....
          aListOfNetworkLogs[tab.id].push(sCompleted);
     ....
});

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.action == "getNetworkLog") {
        port.postMessage(aListOfNetworkLogs[port.tabId]);
    }
});
});
```

Also, not really a problem here but you don't need to call JSON.stringify() and JQuery.parseJSON() for messages because the data are serialized inherently.